# Angular 2: When multiple dialogs are opened at once is there a way to bring one of the dialogs in the back to the front?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mddialog

I have a issue where a dialog is opened right after another one but want the user to interact with the dialog that was opened first.  Is there a way to bring that first dialog to the front?

Comment: Opening multiple dialogs is not inline with the material philosophy. Can you provide some context?

Comment: You could try to mess with the z-index to bring the item in front of the other dialog. But as Mathieu said, you should not be having two dialogs at once.